# Alternate way to assert Exception thrown from private method in java

Tags: java, exception, reflection, junit

I need to assert that `CustomException` is thrown from one of the private utility method `doSomething`

This is what I implemented so far and is working.

Define rule at test class level 
`@Rule
    public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();`

Relevant part of test method

```
exception.expect(CustomException.class);
// prepare call to executePrivateMethod
try {
        executePrivateMethod(objInstance, "doSomething",
                arg0, arg1);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        Assert.assertTrue("Invalid exception thrown",
                (e.getCause() instanceof CustomException));
        throw (CustomException) e.getCause();
    }

    Assert.fail("Invalid response");
```

I want to know if there is / are alternate  / elegant way available to achieve this? 
**P.S.:** 
1. Very helpful [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/whats-the-proper-way-to-test-a-class-with-private-methods-using-junit) but no mention of my scenario
2. `executePrivateMethod` uses reflection to invoke private method

Comment: I would favour making the method package private, possibly as part of a package private helper class. KISS.

Comment: As an aside, _why_ do you need to know that the custom exception is thrown from the private method? You should generally try to test the exposed interface to your units under test, otherwise, if you change the implementation, your tests will start to fail for no valid reason.

Comment: @assylias Agreed but that's possible only when you have access to source code; which i don't :(

Comment: @DaveHowes The exposed interface have multiple steps. Each step is implemented as private helper method. To ascertain that individual steps' integrity is maintained and proper error handling is done I need to test them.

Answer (score 1):

Your design is typical for when you need to do additional verification when an exception is thrown. The only comment I would make is that you don't need the `fail`, `exception.expect` takes care of that for you.

Also, you don't need to and should not cast to a `CustomException`. This could result in a `ClassCastException` instead of the nice error message stating `expected CustomException, received SomeOtherException`.